# Matplotlib histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a simple histogram. I have processed my data as a list:
X = [30, 2728, 2894, 2582, 2309, 2396, 2491, 2453, 2382, 2325, 2225, 2359, 2138...]

where every position corresponds to the number of items with that value (so 30 items for 0, 2728 for 1, etc.)
If I plot this list as a bar chart I get the desired result but the resolution is too high (i.e. every value is a bucket). What I want to do is to merge buckets so I can get as my X values: 0, 1-10, 10-50, 50-150, 150-500 and as Y values the sum of items in the desired range, so for 0 I will have y value 30, for 1-10 I will have value sum(2728, 2894, 2582, 2309, 2396, 2491, 2453, 2382, 2325, 2225), etc.

I tried this way:

```
plt.hist(X,bins=[0,1,10])
```

but I don't get the desired result, I expect to get one bar 0-1 with y=30 and a second bar 1-10 with y=24785, but that's not what it plots.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to merge the buckets into a customized list:
0, 1-10, 10-50, 50-150, 150-500.
Since this is a customized list, I'm not sure if you can directly tell `plt.hist` what the bins are. I would suggest manually counting how many values are in each of the customized bins. It greatly helps if you transform your list `X` into a NumPy array using `np.array()`.

```
    X = np.array([30, 2728, 2894, 2582, 2309, 2396, 2491, 2453, 2382, 2325, 2225, 2359, 2138])
    ##Customized bin list:
    bin_list = np.array( [0,1,10,50,150, 500, np.inf ])   ##Can specify 500 to be inf as well
    plot_bin = np.zeros( len(bin_list)-1)
    for bin_n in range(len(bin_list)-1):
       plot_bin[bin_n] = np.sum( (X >= bin_list[bin_n]) & (X < bin_list[bin_n+1]) )

    ## Create string version of the buckets to use as labels
    str_bin_list_lower = [str(a) for a in bin_list[0: -1 ]]
    x_ticks = np.arange(len(bin_list)-1)-0.35
    plt.bar( x_ticks, plot_bin)
    plt.xticks( x_ticks+0.35, str_bin_list_lower )
```

Editted: I misunderstood your question. You have a bin list of [0,10,50] and want to add the numbers from [0], [1-10], [10-50], etc. You should be more familiar with how Python indexes elements. For example, `range(10)[0:5] = [0,1,2,3,4]` and `range(10)[5:10] = [5,6,7,8,9]`. You need to account for this when you make your bin list. 
Then the binning process should be:

```
    X = np.array([30, 2728, 2894, 2582, 2309, 2396, 2491, 2453, 2382, 2325, 2225, 2359, 2138])
    bin_list = np.array( [0,10,50,150, 500, np.inf ])+1   ##Can specify 500 
    plot_bin = np.zeros( len(bin_list)-1)
    for bin_n in range(len(bin_list)-1):
      if bin_n==len(bin_list)-2:
        plot_bin[bin_n] = np.sum( X[ bin_list[bin_n]: ] )
      else:
        plot_bin[bin_n] = np.sum( X[ bin_list[bin_n]:bin_list[bin_n+1]+1] )
    plot_bin = np.insert(plot_bin, 0, X[0])
```

Comment: I think this is the right approach, but plot_bin is [  0.   0.   1.   0.   0.  12.] while it should be [30,24785,4497,0,0,0] ( because sum of values between index 0 and index 1 is 30, sum of values between index 1 and index 10 is 24785 and sum of values between index 10 and index 50 is 4497, and there are no elements in the array at index > 12 so the remaining buckets are empty). I think I can either manually re-bin my data or use np in a smart way (like your answer suggests).

Comment: Ah, I see that I misunderstood your original question. Where are you getting 24785 and 4497? Overall, I think you can use `np` to get the data the way you want it.

Comment: I am summing all values at index 1:10 (2728, 2894, 2582, 2309, 2396, 2491, 2453, 2382, 2325, 2225) that's how I get 24785. Then I sum index 10:50 (2359, 2138) which gives me 4497.

Comment: Editted to reflect this. I misunderstood your original intent.

Answer (score 1):

For the way you preprocess data the right way to plot it is:

```
X = [30, 2728, 2894, 2582, 2309, 2396, 2491, 2453, 2382, 2325, 2225, 2359, 2138]
plt.bar(range(len(X)),X);
```

[image]

However, `matplotlib` provides an even easier and more straightforward way to plot a histogram:

```
x = np.random.randn(1000)
plt.hist(x, bins=30);
```

[image]

If you want a more direct control over binning, you may want to switch to Pandas and try [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) where you can define your own bins:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randint(0,100,1000)})
factor = pd.cut(df.x, [1,10,20,100])
df.groupby(factor).apply(lambda x: x.count()).plot(kind='bar', rot=45, legend=0);
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I am saying, the plt.bar(range(len(X)),X); method works but I want to merge the buckets. How do I merge them?

Comment: @StefanD I think the easiest way to draw a nice histogram is to preprocess your data properly and then call matplotlib's `plt.hist()` or pandas' `pd.hist()`. Why would you want to (1) bin your data and then (2) re-bin it again once you discovered the histogram (which is a bar plot actually) is not as nice as you hoped? If you do not like the binning you get, I think you should step back and re-bin your data.

Comment: @pushmarov I intent to use the bar plot to help me visualize my distribution so I can understand what the right bin sizes and splits are. The ultimate goal is to split the data not to generate a nice plot. The plot is just the tool I am using to understand my distribution,